# how to hide element in specific page

Tags: magento-1.7, category

I have an element in header.phtml that shows in every page but I want to hide it in specific pages like categories and products.

```
<ul id=tempMenu>
 <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

and the php code

```
<?php if(!Mage::registry('current_category')):?>
  <script>
    document.ready(function() {
      document.getElementById('tempMenu').style.display = 'none';
    });
  </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I'm really new to magento so if anyone can help me I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript for that.

Just wrap your `ul` with PHP logic in `header.phtml`.

Hide element on all category and product pages:

```
 <?php if (!(Mage::registry('current_category') || Mage::registry('current_product))):?>
   <ul id=tempMenu>
    <li>...</li>
   </ul>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
<?php if(Mage::registry('current_category') || Mage::registry('current_product')):?>
  <script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery('#tempMenu').hide();
    });
  </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove header block with custom layout update.

On your Admin Panel, `Manage Categories -> Your Sepecific Category -> Custom Design -> Custom Admin Panel`

```
<reference name="header">
   <remove name="header"/>
</reference>
```